# Automatic code formatting for Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

I use many brackets and braces when I code. Be it casting multiple times, casting multiple times in if blocks, etc. I sometimes get lost in the brackets and also, hate putting a lot of them.
Is there any short-cut key to format this selected part of code?
I have tried Ctrl-Shift-F, but that doesn't give me what I want.
Note: I work on Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Did you check out the eclipse save actions and code formatting?

Comment: @Tobi: Yes i checked the box named: Additional Actions and in that too I did not find it. and code formatting, i could not search it (tried typing in the search box above it. that's what i see in my eclipse mars.) could you guide me?

Comment: save actions as in the answer. search for  formatter (Java->code style->formatter) there you can edit your profile. Go to the tab braces and check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `Source` menu | `Cleanup`, then customize the profile to add the remove extra parenthesis. From the `Code Style` tab check the `Use parenthesis in expressions` `Only if necessary`. And then complete the wizard:

[image: parens]

That changes:

```
super.start(((BundleContext)(context)));
```

to:

```
super.start(context);
```

As an extra you can set your project to do code cleanup tasks on save automatically if you desire.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonah, you made my coding-life easier :D

Comment: just one thing mate, I have to configure the settings for a specific project, and then it works. Perfect. What if I want these settings to be my default settings, so that it works for all my projects?

Comment: Change the clean up actions in Preferences | Java | Code Style | Clean Up. You can add save actions globally with Preferences | Java | Editor | Save Actions

Comment: Thanks a ton @Jonah :)

Comment: What if I want that from the whole java file, i want only the specific code, say i introduce a new method in a class having 10 methods (which i do not want to be modified. keep them as it is) and then change that part according to the options i want. How could I achieve it?
Just select that part and save it? But, won't that again change the whole other code? Which i want to remain untouched?

Comment: @abhi I don't know off hand, perhaps a new SO Question would be great.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ctrl+3 and type formate? for me Ctrl-Shift-F was bound by other app and cause eclipse to miss catching it.

Comment: Didn't get what I want. I want something similar to Ctrl-Shift-F. Just one time thing you could say. No navigation or anything.

Comment: He was referring to the Quick Access feature: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html#shortcuts_overview While that doesn't give you a "configure once" solution, you should really know it as it makes navigating eclipse way more easy.

Answer (score 0):

search for formatter `Java->code style->formatter`
There is a tab Braces.

If you select specific lines and press `Ctrl + Shift + F` eclipse will only format the lines you selected according to your formatter.

[image]